# confused with mysql foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

I am a little confused with foreign keys and how they are supposed to work.

i have 3 tables in database

```
database = mydb
table parent = user
table child = hobbies
table child2 = skills

*mydb.user have apID as primary and Auto Increment
*mydb.hobbies have apID with relation with mydb.user apID
and hID as auto increment 
*mydb.skills hace apID with relation with mydb.user apID
and sID as auto increment
```

I am confused on how to insert data so that the apID in hobbies and skills are the same?
Which key in hobbies and skills need to be primary, the foreign or the other?

ok I end up with

```
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`user` (`appID`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, 'pedro');
INSERT INTO `skills` (`appID`,`dipID`,`name``) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),NULL,'running')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have next tables -

```
CREATE TABLE `USER`(
  APID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (APID)
) ENGINE = INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;

CREATE TABLE HOBBIES(
  HID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  APID INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (HID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_HOBBIES_USER_APID FOREIGN KEY (APID) REFERENCES `USER` (APID)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE = INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;

CREATE TABLE SKILLS(
  SID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  APID INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (SID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_SKILLS_USER_APID FOREIGN KEY (APID) REFERENCES `USER` (APID)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE = INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Our ID primary fields are declared as AUTO_INCREMENT, so it is better to use this feature - add NULL value and MySQL will generate new ID value itself (1, 2, 3 and so on) -

```
-- Add first user and all his properties (hobbies, skills)
INSERT INTO user(apID) VALUES(NULL); -- We pass NULL

-- But real ID is 1, we set this value to variable @id
-- This @id will be used to insert correct foreign key values in child tables
SET @id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

-- Add some hobbies and skills for user 1
INSERT INTO hobbies(hID, apID) VALUES (NULL, @id);
INSERT INTO hobbies(hID, apID) VALUES (NULL, @id);
INSERT INTO hobbies(hID, apID) VALUES (NULL, @id);

INSERT INTO skills(sID, apID) VALUES (NULL, @id);
INSERT INTO skills(sID, apID) VALUES (NULL, @id);
INSERT INTO skills(sID, apID) VALUES (NULL, @id);
```

Do the same for each user.

Check results:

```
SELECT * FROM `user`;
+------+
| APID |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+

SELECT * FROM hobbies;
+-----+------+
| HID | APID |
+-----+------+
|   1 |    1 |
|   2 |    1 |
|   3 |    1 |
+-----+------+

SELECT * FROM skills;
+-----+------+
| SID | APID |
+-----+------+
|   1 |    1 |
|   2 |    1 |
|   3 |    1 |
+-----+------+
```

Comment: whats the dfifference in creating a variable or call LAST_INSERT_ID() in every INSERT

Comment: When we insert row into parent table `user` we should remember this PARENT ID value. Then we do INSERT(s) into child tables, these tables are also have AUTO_INCREMENT fields. So, next time, LAST_INSERT_ID() will another value - ID for child table (`hobbies` or `skills`).

Comment: ok, i use this  SELECT MAX(appID) from `db.user` and have no problem with getting the incorrect table auto_increment id

Comment: Of course, you may use this one. In most cases you will benefit from it. But there is no guarantee it is true. You can find this information in the MySQL documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The `primary key` is the column(s) that uniquely identify a row in a table.  For your user table it is just `apID` and for the `hobbies` and `skills` tables it is either just `hID` and `sID` or `hID + apID` and `sID + apID` (depends on what your data represents).

A `foreign key` is a refence to a value in another table. So if you have a foreign key constraint on `apID` in `hobbies` that refences `apID` in `user`, that means that every `apID` in `hobbies` must have a matching `apID` in `user`.  If you try to insert or update a row in `hobbies` or `user` so that a matching pair goes away MySQL will throw an error.

The `hobbies` table might look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE hobbies (
  hID INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  apID INT(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (hID, apID),
  FOREIGN KEY (apID) REFERENCES user(apID) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

The neat thing there is the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` clause.  That will make it so that if you update an `apID` in `user`, the database will update any rows it has to in `hobbies` so that everything stays in synch.  There are also things like `ON DELETE CASCADE`, but if you do a little research those should be easy to find.

As for how to insert the data, you do it as you normally would.  The only caveat is that before you can insert into `hobbies` or `skills`, there has to be a matching `apID` already in the `user` table.

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97071) that shows all this stuff in action.

Answer (score 0):

sorry but what you wrote is a little bit confusing. i hope i understood your problem.

if you have a table `user` with primary key `userID`, and two tables `hobbies` and `skills` that use `user.userID` as foreign keys. 
You will need a primary key in both `hobbies` and `skills` (e.g. `hobbiesID` and `skillsID`). `userID` can't be the primary key of `hobbies`/`skills`, because it would not be unique; it is just used as foreign key to form the relation between the `user`table and the `hobbies`/`skills`tables.

Answer (score 0):

1.table parent = user
Here apID  is primary key

2.table child = hobbies
here hID is primary key and apID is foreign key

3.table child2 = skills
here sID is primary key and apID is foreign key

--INSERT COMMANDS

1.INSERT INTO user

2.INSERT INTO hobbies
here you have to select apID from users table

3.INSERT INTO skills
here you have to select apID from users table

Comment: thanks i was more confuse in which table need the primary key and and to where and from the foreign key goes,  If am not correct please help me, depending on where you call/put the foreign key that determine what makes a relationship 1 to 1 or 1 to many or many to many ?